# Conversion from hex to signed int not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I'm trying to convert this hex string `F1` into a signed integer.
So I should get as result `-15`

I have this Python function right here which works good, but somehow doesn't work for this string `F1`

Code:

```
def get_signed_value(value):
    return -(value & 0x8000) | (value & 0x7fff)
```

If I pass for example `FF5F` as value, then I get `-161` as response which is correct.
But if I pass `F1` I get `241` as response which is not the correct value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your function is designed for a 16-bit number with a value range of `−32.768 (0x8000) to 32.767 (0x7fff)`, while `0xf1` is only a 8-bit number with a value range of `-128 (0x80) to 127 (0x7f)`. Thus, the `return` statement in the function doesn't apply correctly.

You have to change the function according to what is the number of bits in your hex number. For 8-bit:

```
def get_8bit_signed_value(value):
    return -(value & 0x80) | (value & 0x7f)
```

Then

```
get_8bit_signed_value(int('0xf1', 16))
```

returns your desired `-15` for `0xf1`. You can automate this function for bitnumbers with `nbits` digits by calculating the value range limits by `1 << (nbits-1)`